# VB.Net Switch Statement, include code segment in every case

Tags: vb.net, switch-statement

So I am writing a program in VB.Net and have a simple question about the Select/Case statement that I can't seem to find an answer to.  So right now my Case looks something like this:

```
Select Case numColumns
    Case 0
        numColumns = numColumns + 1
        'Some code
    Case 1
        numColumns = numColumns + 1
        'Some different code
    Case 2
        numColumns = numColumns + 1
        'Some even more different code
    Case Else
        'Do Nothing
End Select
```

Essentially, I need to have the `numColumns = numColumns + 1` statement in every Case **except** for the `Case Else`.  Is there a way to do this without adding the same code line to every Case statement?

The simple solution I can think of is to maybe have an if statement before my select, and do the increment there, but I am wondering if there is a way to do it with like a `Case All` line or something.

Comment: Do you need to increment before the "Some Code" part? If not, you could keep a variable that is initialized to 1 and set to 0 in the else and use that to increment.

Comment: @the_lotus Yes, I need to increment before the `'Some Code` segment.

Comment: Are you saying you *have* to use a Case statement? If the cases are contiguous, i.e. 0, 1, 2 then you could just use an If():

numColumns = numColumns + If(numColumns>=0 and numColumns<=2, 1, 0)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should work:

```
Select Case numColumns
    Case 0 To 2
        numColumns = numColumns + 1
        'Some code
    Case Else
        'Do Nothing
End Select
```

**Edit:**

You can solve it with an additional `Select/Case` if you consider it more beautiful than a `If`-statement before:

```
Select Case numColumns
    Case 0 To 2
        numColumns = numColumns + 1

        Select Case numColumns
            Case 0
                'Some code
            Case 1
                'Some different code
            Case 2
                'Some even more different code
        End Select
    Case Else
        'Do Nothing
End Select
```

And if you really "Do Nothing" in the `Else`-part, then you can omit it completely.

Comment: Sorry, I should have specified in my original post that the `'Some code` in each Case statement was different, so using `To` won't exactly work here.

Comment: Maybe you should refactor the code and provide a method that you can call with the integer argument. Then you can use a single `Case 0 To 2` and call this method there. The logic `Some code`/`Some different code` should be encapsulated there.

Answer (score 3):

you could try starting it off with the increment

```
numColumns = numColumns + 1
Select Case numColumns - 1
    Case 0
        'Some code
    Case 1
        'Some different code
    Case 2
        'Some even more different code
    Case Else
        numColumns = numColumns - 1
        'Do Nothing
End Select
```

Answer (score 0):

Just another example.

```
Private _numColumns As Integer

Public Property NumColumns As Integer
Get
    Return _numColumns 
End Get
Private Set(value As Integer)

    _numColumns = value

    '**************************************
    'NOTE: You could place your Select Case statement here (I don't recommend doing this though).
    'Maybe add logic to see if "value" is less than or greater a "_minColumn" and "_maxColumn" constant before assigning it (constants are not declared in this sample).
    '**************************************

End Set
End Property

Private Sub IncrementNumColumns()
    NumColumns += 1
End Sub

'Not currently used -- Here as an example. 
Private Sub DecrementNumColumns()
    NumColumns -= 1
End Sub

Private Function CodeSharedByAllColumnFunctions(p_myParam1 As Object, p_myParam2 As Object) As Integer
    IncrementNumColumns()
    'Maybe return some other result here. Otherwise change this to a Sub()
    'If nothing in Process1Column(), Process2Column(), and Process3Column() is reusable, then -
    ' add the IncrementNumColumns() to each method.
End Function

Private Sub Process1Column(p_myParam1 As Object, p_myParam2 As Object)
   Dim _someReusableCalculationResult = CodeSharedByAllColumnFunctions(p_myParam1, p_myParam2)
  'Some more code that unique to a single column
End Sub

Private Sub Process2Column(p_myParam1 As Object, p_myParam2 As Object)
     Dim _someReusableCalculationResult = CodeSharedByAllColumnFunctions(p_myParam1, p_myParam2)
    'Some more code that unique to 2 columns
End Sub

Private Sub Process3Column(p_myParam1 As Object, p_myParam2 As Object)
     Dim _someReusableCalculationResult = CodeSharedByAllColumnFunctions(p_myParam1, p_myParam2)
    'Some more code that unique to 3 columns
End Sub

Private Sub ProcessNumColumns() 
    Dim _someValue1, _someValue2 As Object
    _someValue1 = New With {.something = "abc"}
    _someValue2 = New With {.something = "123"}

Private Sub ProcessNumColumns() 
    Dim _someValue1, _someValue2 As Object
    _someValue1 = New With {.something = "abc"}
    _someValue2 = New With {.something = "123"}

    'Personally I wouldn't use a Select case here. I would use reflection to determine the correct method to call. 
    'I think that's outside of the scope of your question though.
    '
    'For the sake of readability, please do your best to keep the code within each Case to a minimum.
    'If possible, PLEASE avoid nested Select Case statements.
    Select Case NumColumns
        Case 0
            Process1Column(_someValue1, _someValue2)
        Case 1
            Process2Column(_someValue1, _someValue2)
        Case 2
            Process3Column(_someValue1, _someValue2)
    End Select
End Sub
```